# Can we connect to the signalR hub on button click client side?

Tags: jquery, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to connect to a hub on a button click event:
Code:

```js
$("#send").on("click", function () {
            userName = ($("#fname").val()).toString();
            userName = userName.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
            message = ($("#yourMessage").val()).toString();
            message = message.replace(/[\r\n]\s*/g, "");
            message = message.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
            $("#yourMessage").val('');
            $("#send").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#fname").val(userName);
            if ($("#yourMessage").val() == "Start Typing...") {
                console.log("focus");
                $("#yourMessage").val("");
            }
            console.log(userName + " " + message);
            connectedHub(userName);
            
           
        });
var connectedHub=function(){
            var chatName = $("#fname").val();
            $.connection.hub.qs = "ChatName=" + chatName;
            $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    writeToPage("Somehow!");
                    //The Server side announce() is called here
                    myHub.server.serverAnnounce("Connected!!");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/SendMessage?msg=" + message,
                        type: "post",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            var data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
                            console.log("Success");
                            console.log("Server returned " + data2);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            var err = JSON.stringify(response);
                            alert(err);
                        }

                    })
                .fail(function () {
                    writeToPage("Error!");
                })
                });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But on the click event I get this Error:

SelectChatType:207 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hub' of undefined
    at connectedHub (SelectChatType:207)
    at HTMLInputElement. (SelectChatType:188)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (VM104 jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (VM104 jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)

However this 'hub' gets connected and works fine when out of the 'click' event function.

How can I connect to the server side hub on a button click event. Basically, I want the OnConnected() to trigger only on a button click.

Comment: i think you miss tow of signalR files please check again

Comment: @DarshanDave I have rendered those scipts in the _layout. This is just a part of the script. Thanks.

Comment: okay, that may be the issue try to put on same page

Comment: which signalr are you using? `core`?

Comment: ASP.NET SignalR Core @NevilleNazerane

Comment: this seems to be the code for the older version. which documentation did you use for this?

Comment: I'm afraid,I'm trying to learn from online tutorials that are available on YouTube. Would really appreciate if you point me in the right direction. Thanks @NevilleNazerane

Comment: I am not sure if your js is actually what's wrong. But I had used a different code for core

Comment: check this. this is the exact syntax i used https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr-client

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I had used `SignalR core`. First I made the hub class:

```
public class Chat : Hub
{

    public const string Path = "Chat";

    public async Task Notify(int id) {
        await Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Notified", id);
    }

}
```

Then in my startup I used:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<Chat>(Chat.Path);
});
```

Finally I used the following js:

```
    let connection = new signalR.HubConnection(socketURL + '/Chat.Path');

    connection.on('Notified', data => {
        console.log("Socket content:", data);
    });

    connection.start();
```

Note that in my case the web socket server and client were on different websites. Which is why I had to use the `socketURL`, which stored the url. You can try without it.

Comment: I need to connect to the hub on a button click. Thanks in advance.